# Restore working directory in terminal windows when loading session

Tags: neovim, terminal

While using `:mksession` feature, I found that it works well with files and `netrw`, but not so much with neovim `terminal` windows. The problem is that, for terminal, it never preserves working directory inside the shell, even if I `:lcd` before saving the session. It does restore working directory inside `vim` itself, but the shell directory is always the one that was specified when terminal was created.

I'm wondering if there's a way to work around this. I'm thinking about something like calling extra function after session restore to run `cd getcwd()` in every terminal window, but I'm not sure how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to write something that achieves desired effect.

```
function! Terminal_cd()
        if &buftype == 'terminal'
                call chansend(b:terminal_job_id, 'NVIM= cd "' . getcwd() . "\"\<cr>")
        endif
endfunction

function! Terminal_restore()
        let curtab = tabpagenr()
        let curwin = winnr()
        tabdo windo call Terminal_cd()
        exec curtab . 'tabn'
        exec curwin . 'wincmd w'
endfunction
```

I call `Terminal_restore()` after sourcing the session file. Since I already have vim automatically change working directory along with the shell `cd`, this seems to be good enough. Unsetting `NVIM` during restore is done because it is used to detect nvim session and calls `:lcd` automatically from shell function.